Fastlane setup `missing symbol called` mac/swift
I am trying to set up fastlane to automate screenshots for my ios app.
I am have issues with all 3 ways to setup fastlane described here: fastlane setup ios
Each different method eventually leads me to getting an error of the form: dyld[xxxxx]: missing symbol called which is not a very helpful error message and has left me stumped as i am unsure as to what the root cause is.
I am certain i have the latest xcode command line tools installed and my ruby version is: ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin23], which is greater than the required 2.5 by fastlane.
For bundler:
when i run gem install bundler: missing symbol called
when i run gem install --user-install bundler: missing symbol called
i have tried setting up an rvm or rbenv but these result in the same issues.
I then tried to install fastlane using homebrew:
i got much further using this method, but eventually ended up with the same problem
fastlane seemed to install fine, however when i ran fastlane init swift (option 1 for automating screenshots), i got through until the step where i must enter my apple id credentials, and then after i put in my correct username and password: missing symbol called
as an alternative i tried pressing 4 for a manual setup, but it seemed to me that the generated fastlane files were riddled with errors such as deprecated swift functions and scoping errors
for System Ruby + RubyGems
as a last resort i tried sudo gem install fastlane , after fetching a large chunk of files, I eventually got to the missing symbol called error again.
I am at a loss as what to try next, please let me know if there is any more information i can provide and any possible solutions are welcome - thanks!
